# Service/Method for forwarding A record

Tags: dns

I am setting up a WordPress multisite with numerous subsites.  Some of these subsites will have a custom domain.  I may end up switching hosting providers down the road and want to avoid having to get my clients to switch their records when I do so.

Is there a way to set up the DNS flow so that it is:

```
Client's DNS A Record > Redirection controlled by me > final server
```

rather than:

```
Client's DNS A Record > final server
```

Would this be too slow?

Comment: Ask your clients to do a `CNAME` record towards a name you control, instead of a direct `A` record, otherwise they will have to update it once you change your hosting.

Answer (score 6, accepted):

You cant do this with an A record, and arguably the DNS spec is remiss in not having something that works exactly as you propose.

Setting up an A record for a subdomain you control and replacing the clients A record with a CNAME is as close as you can get. **This only works correctly for the clients subdomain - ie [www.clientdomain.example](http://www.clientdomain.example) is OK but clientdomain.example will not work as intended.**

Some domain providers have come up with an artificial construct called an Alias record.  This attempts to emulate the behaviour you are after by appearing like an A record when queried, with the DNS service flattening the alias to an A record. This implementation is provider specific and somewhat implementation specific and requires your clients to use their systems to flatten the domain - so while useful its not a generic answer.